# How we can get the data from azure file share to on premises

Tags: azure-storage, azure-files

I'm investigating whether the feature to copy multiple folders 
(Exports from Collections) from Azure File Share to onPremise Accelerate file share (windows share) exists or not.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a "recommend a tool/solution" question.  this is not the goal of the site.  please provide/document the steps you have taken to try to solve this problem

Comment: Thanks for advising, but sometime small information helpful if suggested in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Azure file share is indeed supported in the Import/Export process:

*"Azure Import/Export service is used to securely import large amounts of data to Azure Blob storage and Azure Files by shipping disk drives to an Azure datacenter"*

You can read more about the feature and when it's best used [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-import-export-service)